# Two ip check in the .htaccess's if statement

Tags: .htaccess

I try to give access to two of my IP's to a page on my site in the .htaccess but it's a issue with my if statment that just the first IP checks and never checks the secound IP. My code is:

```
<If "%{REMOTE_ADDR} != '123.123.123.123'" AND "%{REMOTE_ADDR} != '456.456.456.456'">
RedirectMatch ^/mypage$ example.com [R=302,L]
</If>
```

I have tested with `&&` insted for `AND` but it not work. What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> <If "%{REMOTE_ADDR} != '123.123.123.123'" AND "%{REMOTE_ADDR} != '456.456.456.456'">
> RedirectMatch ^/mypage$ example.com [R=302,L]
> </If>
> ```

You have multiple syntax errors here:

- As you pointed out, you need to use `&&`, not `AND` in the expression. There is no operator `AND`.
- The double quotes `"` should surround the entire expression. You essentially have two separate expressions, which is not supported.
- The `RedirectMatch` mod_alias directive is invalid. The 3rd (flags) argument `[R=302,L]` is part of the mod_rewrite `RewriteRule` directive and is not permitted here. The target URL (2nd argument) needs to be either a root-relative or absolute URL.

This should be written like this instead:

```
<If "%{REMOTE_ADDR} != '123.123.123.123' && %{REMOTE_ADDR} != '456.456.456.456'">
    RedirectMatch 302 ^/mypage$ https://example.com/
</If>
```

However, I would consider using mod_rewrite for this instead. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=123.123.123.123
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=456.456.456.456
RewriteRule ^mypage$ https://example.com/ [R=302,L]
```

NB: There is no slash prefix on the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

If you are intending to "block" access, consider sending a 403 Forbidden, instead of redirecting. For example:

```
:
RewriteRule ^mypage$ - [F]
```

Or, if using `RedirectMatch` inside the `<If>` expression:

```
RedirectMatch 403 ^/mypage$
```